# Creating an alias to another Clojure namespace

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I have some private functions in one namespace that I would like to include in a second namespace. e.g.

```
(ns one)

(defn ^:private foo 
  "A docstring"
  [x] (* x 2))
```

And the second namespace needs to create an alias to this:

```
(ns two)

(def foo ???)

(foo 3)   ;; should work as if the function in namespace one was called
=> 6
```

Ideally I'd like to preserve the docstring so I don't have to maintain it in two places. Also I'd like to have the option to either use the same name or a different name.

The reason for this requirement is as follows: the functionality is needed/used in namespace `one`. `one` is a dependency of `two`, and since we can't have circular dependencies it won't work to define `foo` within `two` itself. `two` is the public API, so `foo` needs to be publicly part of the `two` namespace.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You want the alias name to be same or it can be anything?

Comment: @Ankur - currently looking to use the same name, but in some cases it might also be useful to create an alias with a different name so it would be great if the solution allowed that.

Comment: Try this: `(def foo (with-meta one/foo (meta #'one/foo)))`

Comment: Which begs the questions: Why is `foo` in `one`? And why is it private? Obviously it should be in `two` and public...

Comment: @kotarak - good question, have added the explanation in the question, but basically it's because `two` is the public API.

Comment: @mikera put everything in `two` with non-public parts marked with `^:private`?

Comment: @kotarak - this is sometimes useful in python (where it's easy to do).  it lets you maintain code in several files and then agglomorate them for "publishing" to the user.  it's a good question and the answer isn't "don't do that".

Comment: @andrewcooke @mikera There is always `load` to split up namespaces in files. `(ns two) (defn foo...) (load "one") <rest of two>` and in one.clj `(in-ns 'two) ...` Immigrating is as old as compojure. It doesn't really work, because it doesn't actually create an alias. "Don't do it." is probably the best answer.

Comment: I know it is possible to merge everything into one namespace. But I definitely *don't* want to do this. Wanting to expose one symbol in a public API shouldn't force you to restructure your entire project! And taken to its logical conclusion, this would mean that everything would ultimately end up in one massive namespace which really defeats the point of namespaces in the first instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
(ns one)

(defn- foo 
  "A docstring"
  [x] (* x 2))

(ns two)

(def foo-alias #'one/foo)
(alter-meta! #'foo-alias merge (select-keys (meta #'one/foo) [:doc :arglists]))
```

The trick is to not resolve the symbol 'one/foo, hence avoiding to trigger the private flag on its metadata. Then after aliasing foo in your second namespace, you simply cherry pick the metadata you want to keep from the previous definition.

Answer (score 0):

The Potemkin library has a function `import-vars` for this kind of thing.

https://github.com/ztellman/potemkin